# Javascript Reduce function returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is converted to array for using reduce function, but its returning `NaN`
Here is the example:

```
const obj = {
"2024-02-08": {
    "mobile": {
        "total": 2,
        "totalrev": 36
    },
    "laptop": {
        "total": 3,
        "totalrev": 535
    }
},
"2024-02-09": 0,
"2024-02-10": 0,
"2024-02-11": 0,
"2024-02-12": {
    "mobile": {
        "total": 5,
        "totalrev": 0
    },
    "laptop": {
        "total": 2,
        "totalrev": 0
    }
},
"2024-02-13": 0,
"2024-02-14": 0,
"2024-02-15": 0,
"2024-02-16": 0
}
```

Suppose i want to calculate total rev of the laptop , so i am using this reduce function

```
const totalRevFromLaptop = Object.values(obj).reduce( (acc, cur) => acc + cur?.laptop?.totalrev, 0 );
```

But its returning `NaN`

Comment: Try `(cur?.laptop?.totalrev ?? 0)`

Comment: @TheMaster Not works with that. Returns 0.

Comment: Added brackets.

Comment: `acc + cur?.laptop?.totalrev || acc` would also work, but the other solution is more readable I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the optional chaining operation returns `undefined` and when it is added to the `acc`umulator, it returns `NaN`. Use null coalescing operator to change  `undefined` to 0 before adding to the accumulator.

```
(cur?.laptop?.totalrev ?? 0)
```

```js
const obj = {
    "2024-02-08": {
        "mobile": {
            "total": 2,
            "totalrev": 36
        },
        "laptop": {
            "total": 3,
            "totalrev": 535
        }
    },
    "2024-02-09": 0,
    "2024-02-10": 0,
    "2024-02-11": 0,
    "2024-02-12": {
        "mobile": {
            "total": 5,
            "totalrev": 0
        },
        "laptop": {
            "total": 2,
            "totalrev": 0
        }
    },
    "2024-02-13": 0,
    "2024-02-14": 0,
    "2024-02-15": 0,
    "2024-02-16": 0
    }
        
        
const totalRevFromLaptop = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (cur?.laptop?.totalrev ?? 0), 0 );
console.log(totalRevFromLaptop)
```